# Increasing user id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question I have a table of users with two fields id which is already the primary key and auto increment however I have another field that is called user_id which is separate that I'll need to have auto increment but the first row inserted will have a value of 10000 in the db and increment after that.

Here's my function so far for creating a user in the database. How can I with as less code as possible have it insert the first row as 10000 and then add 1 after that.

```
/**
 * Create new user record
 *
 * @param   array
 * @param   bool
 * @return  array
 */
function create_user($data)
{
    $data['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->db->set('username', $data['username']); 
    $this->db->set('password', $data['password']); 
    $this->db->set('password2', $data['password2']); 
    $this->db->set('email', $data['email']);
    $this->db->set('first_name', $data['first_name']);  
    $this->db->set('last_name', $data['last_name']); 


    $query = $this->db->insert('users');

    if ($query) 
    {
        $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        if ($activated) $this->create_profile($user_id);
        return array('user_id' => $user_id);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's easiest to do this directly with the database rather than through your framework. Also, you can only have one auto increment column per table.

Comment: Agreed w/@BrianDriscoll. You can achieve this in MySQL, for example, by making the `user_id` an auto-incrementing key (Google it). Keep in mind that PHP is limited to a single thread so while you could, say, have a global `$user_id` incrementer it would only last for the current execution thread and then reset the next time you run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just create your own table for storing the extra number you want to auto increment, in the same manor mySQL does it. Only difference is mySQL has a built in function to support it on a per table basis for iNT columns. But the built in option is for one row and one row only.

Do as it does in essence by creating a table ID = tinyINT(4), user_id = INT(11)

Insert a new row, ID = 1, user_id = 10000

before you insert into your other table query for this new table get the user_id +1 to it, and update it.. then use that new number to insert with on the other table.

I realize this has the concept of overhead on it for the extra 2 queries but it serves the purpose needed. Actually if you build a JOIN query the right way you can likely do this in all in single query for the most part

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement for this. Dont know how you apply it in your database library. But its plain SQL. See my MySQL console log.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `users`(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(10), 
    `user_id` INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(`name`), 
    UNIQUE KEY (`id`)
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, 'name1', 10000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO users SELECT null, 'name2', MAX(`user_id`)+1 FROM `users`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO users SELECT null, 'name2', MAX(`user_id`)+1 FROM `users`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `users`;
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | user_id |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | name1 |   10000 |
|  2 | name2 |   10001 |
|  3 | name3 |   10002 |
+----+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How is it going to know if its the first row or not though through the php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
$this->db->set('username', $data['username']); 
$this->db->set('user_id', 'MAX(user_id)+1');
$this->db->set('password', $data['password']);
...
```

And create the first user where user_id is 10000. That way, 10000 is the MAX.

Comment: If I read this right, 10000 is the absolute minimum, not maximum.

Comment: @editor - after manually adding just 1 user, then the max would be 10000 - so, the next time a user is added with this method, the user_id would be 10001.

Comment: @DampeS8N - you're correct, but can you have multiple auto-inc fields in the same table?

Comment: So how will it know that its the first row upon the first entry which should be 10000

Comment: I'm suggesting that you manually create the first user with user_id of 10000. If your app needs to handle this logic, then you could make a call prior to this to get the max user_id if it exists. If not, set it to 10000. If so, set it to MAX(user_id)+1.

Comment: Also, after a little further review, this may not work as written. If it doesn't, then you'd have to use subqueries as @Shiplu suggested.